# Error running teaspoon : rake teaspoon failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, teaspoon

I just installed 'teaspoon' as follows:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "teaspoon-jasmine"
end
```

Then I used this command :

```
rails generate teaspoon:install
```

Then I run:

```
bundle exec teaspoon
```

And I get following error:

```
rake teaspoon
Starting the Teaspoon server...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:55955/teaspoon/default
Failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:55955/teaspoon/default?reporter=Console
rake teaspoon failed
```

It doesn't throw any reason for the error. Is there a way to see the error so that I can fix it or anyone knows solution to it ?